# Angular scope and Kendo UI controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Suppose I have following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
   <title>LOG</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="panel panel-success">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">Log data</div>
     <div class="panel-body">

     <!-- List group -->
       <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Start processing at  {{StartProcessing }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Finished processing at {{EndProcessing }}</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="logTvId" kendo-tree-view
         k-data-source="treeData">
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

and following controller code:

```
 Arch.LogController = function ($scope, $resource, $routeParams)
    {

        var LogResource = $resource('log/:markerId', {}, {
            get: {method: "GET", isArray: false}
        });

       LogResource.get({markerId: $routeParams.markerId}, function (data1)
        {

            $scope.StartProcessing = new Date(data1.StartProcessing).toLocaleString();
            $scope.EndProcessing = new Date(data1.EndProcessing).toLocaleString();

            $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ data: [
                { text: "Item 1" },
                { text: "Item 2", items: [
                    { text: "SubItem 2.1" },
                    { text: "SubItem 2.2" }
                ] },
                { text: "Item 3" }
            ]});

       });
    };
```

After page load I can see StartProcessing and EndProcessing on page, but  I can't see treeview. If I take out code related to $scope.treeData from resource load (say the next instruction after)
then everything  works as expeteced. If I add $scope.$apply() to my initial controller code it throws exception...

What I'm doing wrong? Should I deal with promises ($q ??)  and wait after resource is loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `ng-app` defined...not able to see that.

Comment: It is defined in another file... As I've said it works because I can see Date values. It is simply a pair of controller-template of a whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually problem is solved. In resource handler I create kendo treeview by "hand" (via jquery, as usual), so I'm not using kendo-tree-view directive. Simple div with id + jquery.